# Beginner Balcony Gardner

Tags: dill

My anthem dill was doing well and now it's not. I cut a lot away but feel like I need to cut more. Also, I read that it could be powdery mildew. What is wrong with my dill?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please give us a less blurry photo? It’s really hard to see what’s going on. If you can include some general details (like is it in sun or shade, recent temperature, did you fertilize, ...), it would also be nice. But an in-focus photo is probably most important.

Comment: Okay thank you let me figure out how to add a new photo!!! It’s in afternoon sun for about 3 to 5 hours and then evening sun for about an hour.  It’s Houston so we have had 90 degrees down to 60 and humid one day and not the next ...very unpredictable this time of year! The nursery I got it from potted it for me and did add fertilizer and mulch on the top of the soil!